# Error: The method 'FallThroughError' isn't defined for the class 'ActionCodeInfo'. - 'ActionCodeInfo' is from 'package:firebase_auth_

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

[image]

I opened one of my old projects and it is showing me this Firebase error.
tried rebuilding the Flutter, and upgrading dependencies but it does not work.
How to resolve this error?

the complete error is

Error: The method 'FallThroughError' isn't defined for the class 'ActionCodeInfo'.

- 'ActionCodeInfo' is from 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/action_code_info.dart' ('/C:/Users/Rohit/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.10.1/lib/src/action_code_info.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FallThroughError'.
  throw FallThroughError();
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^